# Corrupted USB Drive in exFat format

Tags: windows, data-recovery, usb-storage

I was backing up some files from my laptop to my 1TB USB Drive in exFat format.

During the file transfer, the progress suddenly stopped and I got the message "The Semaphore Timeout Period Has Expired". The file explorer freezed and I was forced the end the process. Then I proceed to press the "remove usb drive safely" and then I replug the drive.

All of a sudden my drive is not accessible and file system not recognised. Please find the screenshot in the following link.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/3qbWK.jpg

I am now scanning the disk using testdisk.

Is it possible for me to recover the data inside the drive?

Many thanks for your help!

Comment: Perhaps you should replace the drive, like one does with any defective drive.

Comment: Many thanks for your reply.  I encountered the "semaphore" error before and I suspect it is due to the loose cable. For some reasons the cable does not plug firmly to the drive.

Comment: Consider that a loose extension cable that breaks a connection, interrupting writing to the USB, is equivalent to yanking the drive out without gracefully ejecting it. It *might* be possible to use a forensic/salvage tool on it to recover data... or not. If the data is *very* valuable, you might try commercial data recovery, at some expense.

Comment: If the cable doesn't fit properly, it was just an accident waiting to happen. It now happened. Your best bet is to strip the drive from the enclosure & test in another with proper connectivity, see if you got away with it. After that, it's a data recovery service. I presume you're only asking us here because you failed to employ a proper backup strategy.

Comment: Please don't vandalise your question. If you managed to find an answer, please provide it in the answer space below. It is perfectly acceptable to answer your own question, & indeed accept it as 'correct'.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was resolved after performing a scan with test disk.
Thanks all for the help!

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/1074903)

Comment: @MMM The OP is the author and the point you make is a good one